# Difference between ValueNotifier and Bloc/Getx state management libraries?

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

What is the main difference between ValueNotifier and the state management libraries like Bloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueNotifier` is a `ChangeNotifier` that holds a single value and notifies it's listeners when that value changes.

State management libraries, such as `flutter_bloc`, manages simple and/or complex states with single or multiple values and state combinations where different tasks can be performed based on the state together with input by e.g. method calls, timers, value streams etc. etc. It can then notify its listeners about said states when they change.

Furthermore, BLoC is commonly referred to as a design pattern, and the library `flutter_bloc` is made to make it easier to implement it.